# configuring aurelia.json to load googleapis npm packages

Tags: typescript, npm, aurelia, google-oauth

I'm trying to configure aurelia.json in an aurelia typescript appliction to include googleapis npm package that it gets loaded by the loader, but during building/bundling with aurelia-cli I always get errors.

thats the way i have added it to aurelia.json

```
 {
        "name": "googleapis",
        "main": "build/src/index",
        "path": "../node_modules/googleapis",
        "resources": []
      },
      {
        "name": "googleapis-common",
        "main": "build/src/index",
        "path": "../node_modules/googleapis-common",
        "resources": []
      },
      {
        "name": "google-auth-library",
        "main": "build/src/index",
        "path": "../node_modules/google-auth-library",
        "resources": []
      }
```

the errors I get are

```
    ------- File not found or not accessible ------
| Location: c:/projects/xyz/src/google-auth-library.js
| Requested by: c:/projects/xyz/src/resources/elements/html-elements/google-auth-button.js
| Is this a package? Make sure that it is configured in aurelia.json and that it is not a Node.js package
 -----------------------------------------------
 ------- File not found or not accessible ------
| Location: c:/projects/xyz/src/googleapis-common.js
| Requested by: c:/projects/xyz/src/resources/elements/html-elements/google-auth-button.js
| Is this a package? Make sure that it is configured in aurelia.json and that it is not a Node.js package
 -----------------------------------------------
 ------- File not found or not accessible ------
| Location: c:/projects/xyz/node_modules/googleapis/build/src/apis.js
| Requested by: c:/projects/xyz/src/resources/elements/html-elements/google-auth-button.js
| Is this a package? Make sure that it is configured in aurelia.json and that it is not a Node.js package
 -----------------------------------------------
 ------- File not found or not accessible ------
| Location: c:/projects/xyz/src/google-auth-library.js
| Requested by: c:/projects/xyz/src/resources/elements/html-elements/google-auth-button.js
| Is this a package? Make sure that it is configured in aurelia.json and that it is not a Node.js package
 -----------------------------------------------
 ------- File not found or not accessible ------
| Location: c:/projects/xyz/src/googleapis-common.js
| Requested by: c:/projects/xyz/src/resources/elements/html-elements/google-auth-button.js
| Is this a package? Make sure that it is configured in aurelia.json and that it is not a Node.js package
 -----------------------------------------------
 ------- File not found or not accessible ------
| Location: c:/projects/xyz/node_modules/googleapis/build/src/apis.js
| Requested by: c:/projects/xyz/src/resources/elements/html-elements/google-auth-button.js
| Is this a package? Make sure that it is configured in aurelia.json and that it is not a Node.js package
```

what do i have to do to get it working? whats the correct way for using this libraries with aurelia?

Comment: What version of the CLI are you using? From what I understand, you should be able to do this without having to config anything, for the latest version of built-in bundler

Comment: i'm on  3.2.0. do you think an update fixes this bundler issue?

Comment: I'm not sure where you get that version number from. The latest version of Aurelia CLI is 1.0.0-beta.13. Can you try that? Also just need to write: `import ... from 'my-lib'` and let bundler do the work.

Comment: Do you found a solution to this problem ?